# How can you redirect all traffic to one IP or domain on your network?

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt

How can you redirect all traffic to one IP or domain on your network?

So if you went to youtube.com or any IP it would redirect to one domain such as google.com

I have OpenWRT with 128MB of ram.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please add more details.

Comment: What have you tried, and have you searched the internet for this?

https://forum.openwrt.org/t/redirect-all-traffic-to-one-website/60326

Comment: Using a combination of ARP spoofing and DNS spoofing.